# Force charts in two columns to scroll together in flexdashboard

Tags: r, scroll, r-markdown, flexdashboard

I'm dividing up my content into two columns in a `flexdashboard` R Markdown document. There are multiple graphs that fill each column.

Currently, when a user hovers over the "black graphs" on the left, they can scroll down and only the black graphs scroll down. I would like both sets of graphs (black and red) to scroll down together.

Is there any way to set options in `flexdashboard` to force columns to scroll together, at the same time?

*Reproducible example:*

````
---
title: "Multiple Pages"
output: flexdashboard::flex_dashboard
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(flexdashboard)
library(ggplot2)
```

Page 1
=====================================  

Column {data-width=600}
-------------------------------------

### Chart 1 (scrolls separately from Chart 2)

```{r}
plot(cars)
plot(iris)
```

Column {data-width=400}
-------------------------------------

### Chart 2 (I want this to scroll with Chart 1)

```{r}
plot(cars)
plot(iris)
```
````

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, gotta love answering your own question. Not sure why this works, but I added the option `vertical_layout: scroll` in the `yaml` and this forced the columns to scroll together.

```
---
title: "Multiple Pages"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    vertical_layout: scroll
---
```